# Mongoose Aggrigate

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregate

I have seen so many similar questions and answers, but and I'm a bit confused.

How can I achieve this with aggregate in mongoose?

```
const userId = "23523891729417419";

const students = await Students.find({ active: true });
const courses = await Courses.find({ userId: userId });

const result = students.filter((s) => {
    const found = courses.find((c) => c.someId === s.someOtherId);
    if (!found) return s;   
});
```

There is one field (with differnet names) in both models that on some documents the value of them might be equal. I want to exclude them from result.

students and courses are just dummy names. and might mess with the question.

Comment: Could you please give proper model and field names?

Comment: @zx01 I changed it to Students and Courses. 